# Swift NSUserDefaults unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

//Help Please This Code won't work, getting this as feedback from Xcode. 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

---

```
    var savedScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighestScore") as! Int
```

---

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var highestScore:Int = 2
    var score = Int()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        //To save highest score

        //To get the saved score
        var savedScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighestScore") as! Int

        print(savedScore)


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        score += 1
        print("Score - \(score)")

        if score > highestScore
        {
            highestScore = score
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highestScore, forKey:"HighestScore")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            print("Beat")
        }

        else {
            print("Not Beat")
        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the userDefaults function before it ever saves.  You need to check if it exists. First you can make it easier on yourself and just save it as an integer. Then you need to check to see if there is a value.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highestScore, forKey: "HighestScore")

//IntegerForKey will never return nil.  This will return 0 if there is no value.
let savedScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighestScore") 
print(savedScore)
```

Comment: IntegerForKey will never return nil

Comment: Im new to Stackflow so sorry if i checked your comment as a negative but thanks for your help.  I'm trying to fix it right now with both of you and Eliyar Eziz's help

Comment: I did what you said to do and now I'm getting this as my error

Comment: Initializer for condition binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'

Comment: @rMickeyD the correct would be `let savedScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighestScore")`

Comment: @LeoDabus I forgot that integerForKey returns 0 and never nil.  That was an oversight on my part.  Will edit now.

Comment: @rMickeyD integerForKey returns an Int so if you haven't saved any value it will return zero

Comment: Try using what I have now. @LeoDabus added some parentheses I missed at the end of standardUserDefaults()

Comment: @rMickeyD if you get it working can you post your update so I can see how you did it

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults` is a Dictionary Object. If you try to read a value that has not set value before, you will get a `nil`. You could check if the value for key exist

```
let savedScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.integerForKey("HighestScore") ?? 0
```

Then if value for `HighestScore` exist, you will get the correct value, if not, you will set `0` as default value for `savedScore`.

Comment: Im new to Stackflow so sorry if i checked your comment as a negative but thanks for your help.  I'm trying to fix it right now with both of you and rMickeyD's help

Comment: I did what what you suggested and it works with no errors but now it doesn't save the high score when i leave the app and open it up again

Comment: try `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(99, forKey: "HighestScore")` @AmenParham

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I got it yesterday but didn't find time to get on here and post it but here is the code that works. Thank You Guys again that helped!

---

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var score = Int()
    var highScore = Int()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */


        //IntegerForKey will never return nil.  This will return 0 if there is no value.
        highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighestScore")
        print("highScore - \(highScore)")


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        score += 1
        print("Score - \(score)")

        if score > highScore
        {
            highScore = score
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highScore, forKey:"HighestScore")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            print("Beat")
        }

        else {
            print("Not Beat")
        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```